# Database of French companies

Tags: data-request, business, france

Where can I download a database of all French businesses?

It must be free, and contain as much details as possible about each company.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the SIRENE database, maintained by INSEE, part of the French government.
It is the official companies database, and has about 10 millions. It is updated everyday.

It used to cost money, but now it is free:

http://www.sirene.fr/sirene/public/accueil

The database can be downloaded, or browsed online.

For each company, you get:

- Name
- SIRENE and SIRET number
- Address
- Activity category
- Rough number of employees

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for pointing this out! I've been using the https://datainfogreffe.fr so far, but this is much better!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same data and I found a lot of websites using some kind of database like https://societe.com, https://entreprises.lefigaro.fr, https://sireninfo.com etc. So I figured out it was available somewhere for free.

The actual place where you can download the whole database is here:
https://www.data.gouv.fr/en/datasets/base-sirene-des-entreprises-et-de-leurs-etablissements-siren-siret/#_

If you need additional you can use also:
https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/?sort=modified

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what the last link adds, though? If it gives additional properties for each company, would you mind explaining which ones? Cheers!